# Second Schedule for a Morea Course Site

Tags: morea-framework

I'm running my course in parallel for two student tracks but there are some differences in submission dates, so I'd like to mark assessments with 2 different dates and have each track get their own schedule.

Would you add another morea keyword, e.g., morea_start_date2, and then process those into a different file? a quicker idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of is (unfortunately) a hack:

1. In master/src/_plugins/MoreaGenerator.rb, search for "ScheduleInfoFile". You'll see the creation of an instance near the top and the definition of the class near the bottom.  That code looks for the morea_start_date (and morea_end_date) labels and writes out the schedule-info.js file into the schedule/ directory.
2. One approach: you can create a new class called ScheduleInfoFile2 that is a copy of ScheduleInfoFile but looks for your new keywords and writes out a file called schedule-info2.js into a schedule2/ directory.
3. The schedule2/ directory is a copy of the schedule/ directory, but its index.html file loads the schedule-info2.js file.

That should work fine and is simple to implement, but creates a lot of duplicate code and so as a software engineer I am embarrassed to be recommending that approach.  However, this use case is sufficiently rare that I haven't been motivated to generalize Morea to support N calendar pages.

Good luck and feel free to follow up if you run into problems.

Comment: I just ended up putting those 2 schedules on the same calendar page, using FullCalendar's eventSources option:

`eventSources: [
          { color: '#446e9b', events: moreaEventData},
          { color: '#9b446e', events: moreaEventDataM }
      ]`
 
live: http://jce-il.github.io/se-class16b/schedule/
Many thanks, great support! :-)